# Django Nested Tab Form

Tags: python, django, tabs, nested

I have created a template which will recursively build nested tab pages of form/s. Each tab page can contain a form, or another tab page, up to n levels deep.

This is created via a view, where an ordered dictionary (`form_dict`) is passed via the context. In the file forms/snippets/form_dict.html `form_dict` is iterated over, and either renders the form (forms/snippets/form_standalone.html) or calls itself again, if the node contains another ordered dictionary, code has been provided below:

**forms/snippets/form_dict.html**

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}
{% if form_dict %}
    {% if not level or not tier %}
        {% include "forms/snippets/form_dict.html" with form_dict=form_dict level='Tab' tier='0' %}
    {% else %}
        {% with tier=tier|add:1 %}
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-{{tier}}" {%ifequal tier 0 %}id="myTab"{% endifequal %}>
                {% for key,form in form_dict.items %}
                    {% with counter=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}
                        {% with newLevel=''|add:level|add:'-'|add:counter %}
                            <li class="{% ifequal forloop.counter 1 %}active{% endifequal %}">
                                <a href="#{{newLevel}}" data-toggle="tab" {% if form.errors %}class="has-error"{% endif %}>{{key}}</a>
                            </li>
                        {% endwith %}
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content tab-content-{{tier}}">
                {% for k,v in form_dict.items %}
                    {% with counter=forloop.counter|stringformat:"s" %}
                        {% with newLevel=''|add:level|add:'-'|add:counter %}
                            <div class="tab-pane {% ifequal forloop.counter 1 %}active{% endifequal %}" id="{{newLevel}}">
                                {% if v.items %}
                                    {% include "forms/snippets/form_dict.html" with form_dict=v level=newLevel tier=tier %}
                                {% else %}
                                    {% include "forms/snippets/form_standalone.html" with form=v heading=k %}
                                {% endif %}    
                            </div>
                        {% endwith %}
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% ifequal tier 1 %}
                    {% addtoblock 'js' %}
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                            $('.nav-tabs li a').click( function(e) { history.pushState( null, null, $(this).attr('href') );});
                            var hash = location.hash.split('?')[0];
                            if(hash) {
                                var $link = $('[href=' + hash + ']');
                                var parents = $link.parents('.tab-pane').get();
                                $(parents.reverse()).each(function() {
                                    $('[href=#' + this.id + ']').tab('show') ;
                                });
                                $link.tab('show');
                                jQuery(window).load(function(){
                                    jQuery("html,body").animate({scrollTop:0},1);
                                });
                            }
                        </script>
                    {% endaddtoblock %}
                {% endifequal %}
            </div>
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Everything works as expected, except when an error is detected at submission, I want to change the colour of the tabs to reflect that a form under the tab has a problem validating. In the below code:

```
<a href="#{{newLevel}}" data-toggle="tab" {% if form.errors %}class="has-error"{% endif %}>{{key}}</a>
```

This has the effect of identifying the tab (see image below), however, it only highlights a leaf tab -- I want to also assign the same class to the parent tabs as well

[image: Example]

In the above, errors have been identified in both the billing and shipping addresses, I would like the red highlighting to persist upline to parent tabs too, so that both addresses and profile tabs are marked 'red' in a similar fashion.

Can someone offer a suggestion on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works:

I overloaded OrderedDict, to create a property `errors`, so it can be called as if it were a form.

```
class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init(self):
        super(OrderedDict,self).__init__()
    @property
    def errors(self):
        return any([v.errors if hasattr(v,'errors') else False for k,v in self.items()])
```

so in **views.py**, the heirachy is build something like this, for instance:

```
    #Dictionary in Order of Assignment
    fd                        = MyOrderedDict(): #ROOT
    d                         = MyOrderedDict()  #CHILD
    d['Basic']                = formProfile
    d['Phone']                = formClient
    add = MyOrderedDict() #CHILD
    add['Billing Address']    = formAddressBilling
    add['Shipping Address']   = formAddressShipping
    d['Addresses']            = add
    fd['Profile']             = d
    d2 = MyOrderedDict()
    d2['Some Form']           = formSomeForm
    fd['Information']         = d2

return render_to_response('forms/generic_form.html',
            dict(   base_template   = "forms/base.html",
                    form_dict       = fd),
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

This produces the desired output, meaning that no matter which tab the user currently has focus, he/she can readily identify which tabs need to be investigated upon unsuccessful submission.

[image: Output]